# Changes not showing even though React state successfully changes and component rerenders

Tags: reactjs

In my React App I'm calling an API to retrieve some images then display them. I currently have something like this:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

...

const getImages = async () => {
    let newImages = [];
    let data = fetch("url");
    data.then(response => response.json()).then(d => newImages.push(d));
    setImages(newImages);
};

const renderImages = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            {images.map((item, index) => (
                <img src={item.image} alt="something" key={index} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

...


return (
    <div>
        {images && renderImages()}
    </div>
);
```

With logging I checked that the API did retrieve data and it is correctly stored in the `newImages` array before I use `setImages(newImages)`. In a separate useEffect, I even logged the contents of `images` and it contained the intended data. To my knowledge, after the state change React should rerender and the new images should show up, but nothing changes. However, when I change something in VS Code (just adding a comment), which compiles again, the images show up as expected. If I am to assume React does render after I `setImages`, why do the images not display? I was reading about callbacks, but I don't need to execute any more code after `images` is updated; I only need to have `renderImages` reflect the updated `images` data in the JSX return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `data` is a promise :

```
data.then(response => response.json()).then(d => newImages.push(d));
```

it's *asynchronous*, that means `setImages(newImages);` is executed **before** we receive the response.

To fix it:

```
data.then(response => response.json()).then(d => {
  setImages(d)
});
```